# Upload file using angular material 5

Tags: file-upload, angular-material, angular5

I tried to upload file (angular 5) using angular material 5.

app.component.html

```
    <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper">

  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Upload your audio file</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput  
          style="display: none" 
          type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" 
          #fileInput name ="file" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      <button mat-button (click)="fileInput.click()" >Select File</button>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedFile: File=null;
  isLinear = true;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
   this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
     firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
   this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

But I got this error

```
ERROR Error: Input type "file" isn't supported by matInput.
```

knowing this code worked well without angular material. Any issue?

Comment: Looks like is not supported: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#supported-code-lt-input-gt-code-types

Comment: of course isn't supported by angular material. But i am looking for a solution

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem,

Try doing this,

```html
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openInput()">Select File to Upload</button>
    <input id="fileInput" hidden type="file" (change)="fileChange($event.target.files)" name="file" accept=".csv,.xlsv">
```

```js
  openInput(){ 
        document.getElementById("fileInput").click();
   }
```

What above code does is creates simply a Material button and call openInput() method which later on replaces that button to below HTML code

`<input id="fileInput" hidden type="file" >`

This worked for me.

Happy Coding ☻

Comment: At my end this results in:
`ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.`

Comment: importing the following lines in-app modules and then importing them in ng modules imports will solve your problem

`import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';`

Answer (score -1):

> Faster solution would be to use
>   https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload :
>
> ```
> <md-button class='md-raised md-primary' id='uploadFile' ngf-multiple='true' ngf-select='upload($files, $file, $event)'
> ```
>
> type='file'>
>           Upload File
>
> else you would have to go to a custom code like this:
>
> ```
> <label class="md-secondary md-raised md-button" md-ink-ripple for="input-file">
>       <span>Select File to upload</span>
> </label>
> <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="input-file" name="input-file" id="input-file">
> ```

**EDITED:**

In your HTML:

```
 <input #file type="file" nbButton multiple (change)="upload(file.files)" />
```

then in your component:

```
upload(files: any) {
    this.yourServiceToUploadFiles.uploadFile(files).subscribe(
      (response: any) => { .......})}
```

and then in your service:

```
uploadFile(files: any[]): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append(file.name, file);
    }

    return this.http.post(`${apiUrl}/yourServiceEndPoint`, formData, {
      observe: "response",
      responseType: "blob"
    });
  }
```

Comment: it's an AngularJS directive I think, and he's using Angular

Comment: yes and it looks pretty old, let me update my answer.