# Trying to implement as input type as fileupload in angular material

Tags: angular

//my html code//

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
   <mat-label>Image</mat-label>
   <input #fileInput type="file" matInput placeholder="Enter Image" formControlName="Image" 
           (change)="onFileChange($event)" autocomplete="off">
</mat-form-field>
```

//my ts file

```
 onFileChange(event) {

    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const Image = event.target.files[0];
      this.CropDisease.patchValue({
        fileSource: Image
      });
    }
  }
```

//iam getting error

> ERROR Error: Input type "file" isn't supported by matInput.
>       at getMatInputUnsupportedTypeError (input.es5.js:119)
>       at

Comment: Please copy your HTML into the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file using angular material 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456350/upload-file-using-angular-material-5)

Comment: Hi, https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview The file type is not supported.. so if you change `<input #fileInput type="file" matInput placeholder="Enter Image" formControlName="Image" 
           (change)="onFileChange($event)" autocomplete="off">` to `<input #fileInput type="file" placeholder="Enter Image" formControlName="Image" 
           (change)="onFileChange($event)" autocomplete="off">` it will start working.

Comment: //again i get error                                                                                                          mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlErro

Comment: Angular Material supports only a handful of input types and file type is not one of them. You can check more at:

https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#supported-code-lt-input-gt-code-types

You need to add file type outside of <mat-form-field>